# Angular controller sporadically not loading

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs, angularjs-scope

I have a website set up with RequireJS and Angular, but at seemingly random moments, it will decide to either not load part of the Javascript or not databind part of the angular code.

The page in question has several different components on it with their own angular controllers. Everything loads fine about 90% of the time, but sometimes something will happen that prevents databinding (angular brackets visible, ng-hide not working,...). Additionally, the 'network' tab in Chrome devtools shows no files being loaded, though they are listed in 'sources'. I don't know if that is relevant somehow. I get no errors in the console at all.

Digging around in the JS console I've found that one of the broken controllers in question does exist ( = I get an object using `angular.element(...).scope()` ) but when I try to access one of its properties, they are either undefined OR in case of the `init()` function I use in all my controllers, it returns the function of the parent controller.

What could cause the controller to be loaded but its scope variables to be undefined at seemingly random times?

EDIT:
The only way I've found to sort of reproduce this issue without errors showing up in the console is to initialise the controller as an empty function. This produces similar scope behavior in the console, but it doesn't cause the angular curly braces to show up. I will accept any clue that leads me to the cause of the issue or a viable workaround.

Comment: Do you user some JavaScript task runner like [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) or [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) and test your code with unit and especially E2E tests? If you do so, then it's interesting behavior.

Comment: I use Grunt to concatenate and minify all the JS files, but no tests. The problem is that this can happen without an apparant reason, even a simple page refresh can set it off.

Comment: Firstly, try to validate HTML templates to search any mistakes, sometimes the problem lays in spelling of angular naming convention. If not help, we will continue the search.

Comment: And also set the tests environment. For example: [karma](http://karma-runner.github.io/), [phantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) and [jasmine](http://jasmine.github.io/) flavor test. It help you a lot to not prematurely bald.

Comment: @Slyder There are quite a few possible causes for your error. You should add to your question how RequireJS is configured, how you load RequireJS and your application and start your application. Do you use `r.js` (RequireJS's optimizer)? If yes, you should add the `r.js` build configuration to your question.

Comment: You're trying to load your application with Script tags on your Index.html page, aren't you?

Comment: Just to point out, the network tab in chrome dev tools does not show network traffic if dev tools isn't open when the page loads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that RequireJS sometimes loaded everyting fast enough for the angular.bootstrap call to be executed before the DOM was completely loaded. This lead to angular processing what is already loaded and ignoring whatever came next. I therefore added a [domReady](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#pageload) requirement to the setup so I only bootstrap angular when I know the whole page will be there. Since it is hard to know for sure, I can only hope this was the cause and that we won't be seeing this issue again.

Comment: You didn't actually give anyone else enough code to work on, but just to confirm your suspicion, yes, this is what was happening.  You were sporadically seeing it because it was a race condition of some sort.  If you want RequireJS to load Angular and then bootstrap for you, you have to make sure that your dom is finished loading before the Angular bootstrap happens.

Answer (score 1):

You might have to use [AngularAMD](https://github.com/marcoslin/angularAMD). Works great for our angular website.